# What does "|| exit" do in a loop? (Shell scripting)

Tags: shell-script, shell

Example script:

```bsh
for battery in /sys/class/power_supply/BAT?
do
    capacity=$(cat "$battery"/capacity) || exit
    status=$(cat "$battery"/status)
done

echo \[ "$capacity" \| "$status" \]
```

Comment: Same as when not in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you see:

```
some_command || exit
```

That means "If the command terminates with a non-zero exit status, exit the script".  In this context, it means that if `cat`-ing `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT?/capacity` fails for some reason, bail out of the script.